# Solution of $p＝x^2＋y^2$ in $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ and class field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

$p＝x^2＋y^2$ has solution in  $\Bbb Z$ if only if $p＝2$ or $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$(Using easy calculation of quotient ring),  and has solution in  $\Bbb Q$ if only if $p＝2$ or $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$(Using Hilbert symbol).

The condition of $p$ coincidence.

But about $p＝x^2＋26y^2$, it has no solution in $\Bbb Z$ but has solution in $\Bbb Q$.

I heard such phenomenon ( the difference between solution of the form $p＝x^2＋ay^2$ on $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ occurs in a kind of condition of $a$) is deeply related to global class field theory.

But I couldn't find reference.

Could you explain about this issue or give me reference(website) ?

Comment: Your discriminant, $-104,$   has three forms per genus. Any prime $p = 3 u^2 + 2uv + 9 v^2$  cannot be represented (integrally) by $x^2 + 26 y^2.$  Note that, with $7$ not dividing the discriminant, $(11x-5y)^2 + 26 (x+4y)^2 = 147 x^2 + 98 x y + 441 y^2 = 49(3x^2 + 2xy + 9 y^2)$

Comment: I recommend Cox, here is the first edition: http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf